# How to convert a column of dtype object containing key and value pairs, to a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
cc = dataframe.orders
cc.head()

0    {'S0': 50.806451612903224, 'S2': 37.8681626928...
Name: orders, dtype: object
```

I have a column name orders in my df and I want to create a new data frame from that of this structure

```
S0 S1 S2
50 37 33
```

Can someone suggest what should be the code for this in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert to `dict` and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply) to get Series then convert to int with [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas-series-astype):

```py
import ast

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'orders': [
    "{'S0': 50.806451612903224, 'S1': 37.86816269, 'S2': 33.2341234}"
]})

df = df.orders.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(ast.literal_eval(x))).astype(int)

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

```
 S0  S1  S2
 50  37  33
```

Comment: tried this - df = df.orders.apply(pd.Series).astype(float), but getting this error could not convert string to float: "{'S0': 50.806, 'S2': 37.868, 'S1': 43.757}"

Comment: yeah, its type is string not dict